# Docker port binding for Redis with Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, redis, laravel-sail

I have a **multiple** Laravel local projects and I'm trying to change one projects Redis port, so that it doesn't conflict with another project.

**Projects are one the same network** so that they can communicate with one another, but they have separate Redis instances.

This is my Redis service inside docker-compose.yml

```
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '6380:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
```

I'm trying to have Redis available on port `:6380`.

In Docker Desktop I can see, that port bind seems to work correctly:

[image: Docker Desktop Redis service inspect page port binding information]

My `.env` redis section is stock, just changed the port to the new one:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6380
```

### Problem

When I try to run `sail artisan cache:clear` I always get `RedisException Connection refused`.

#### What I have tried

I've tried changing the `REDIS_HOST` environment variable to be exact as container name. Also tried clearing the config with `sail artisan config:clear`. All with no luck.

**Note:** for some reason the `:6379` port is still accessible. I imagine that it shouldn't be as it should be binded to `:6380`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`6380:6379` means port 6379 in the container is going to be available at 6380 **on the host** however when using sail your app is running in another container and not on the host.

The solution is to just change the port Redis is listening on you can modify your docker-compose file:

```
redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    volumes:
        - 'sail-redis:/data'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
    command:
        - redis-server
        - "--port"
        - "6380"
```

An alternative if you don't want to change the container command would be to configure your app to get to redis via the host:

```
REDIS_HOST=172.17.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6380
```

Here 172.17.0.1 is what is set up as the host IP of the docker network by default, however your value may vary

Comment: Thank you. This did solve my issue. But how come for example in the same `docker-compose.yml` changing Laravel service port from 80 to 82 works just fine?

Comment: you connect to your Laravel application from your host (i.e. using a browser outside a container) so changing the port binding will work for that.

Comment: With further testing, sadly this answer only works for a single live Laravel project. 
When I start other Laravel projects with Sail, those projects have shared networks between all of them, then Redis with this configuration fails to load completely.

Comment: for other projects I recommend to use a different name for the network e.g. change `network: - sail` to `network: - myprojectnet` or something like that to isolate each project to its own network. If you do need to have the same network then you only need one of the projects to be running redis and the other ones sharing it

Answer (score 1):

Connections between containers always use the standard port for the destination service; they do not consider `ports:` at all.  No matter what you have `ports:` set to you should keep your current configuration

```bash
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

`ports:` are only needed if you need to access Redis from outside a container, maybe using `redis-cli` for debugging or for doing local development against the container Redis.  If you don't need this, it's safe to just delete the `ports:` block entirely.  If you do keep it, the second number needs to continue to be the standard port number 6379, so change the first port number to a non-conflicting port on the host.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** the issue by simply creating a separate network for shared communication which all separate Redis containers **don't** have access to. This allows me to leave default Redis configuration (except changing binded port to a unoccupied port, but as @david-maze said this doesn't actually have any affect for Redis).